# How to deploy a EAR app as zipped from Eclipse into Wildfly using JBoss Tools plugin?

Tags: eclipse, deployment, jboss, zip, wildfly

My operating system is Windows 7 64-bit.

I am using Eclipse Luna. I have JBoss Tools 4.2.3.Final plugin.

I am using Wildfly 8.2.1.Final in Standalone mode.

I have a EAR app named `TestApp`.

To publish it to Wildfly from Eclipse, in the Servers view, I right click on the Wildfly server to open the pop-up menu and click on Publish option.

When I publish it to Wildfly from Eclipse, it is deployed as **exploded** in `standalone\deployments` directory i.e. a sub-directory named `TestApp.ear` is created in `standalone\deployments` directory which has all the files.

What I want is when I publish it to Wildfly from Eclipse, it is deployed as **zipped**  in `standalone\deployments` directory i.e. a zip file named `TestApp.ear`.

How can I do that?

When I work in Eclipse with old JBoss version 4.2.3, when I deploy to JBoss from Eclipse, it is deployed as **zipped** but how to get the same way with Jboss Tools plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double click on WildFly in "Servers" view which will open its properties page.

There are 2 tabs in it: Overview and Deployment.

Go to "Deployment" tab.

There is an option "Deploy projects as compressed archives" with a checkbox besides it. In you case it is not checked.

Check it then save it.

Next time when you deploy the EAR app it will deploy as compressed.