# JBoss EAP 5.1 - slow deploy startup

Tags: java, jboss

I'm having trouble with slow startup of JBoss 5.1.

```
12:32:34,854 INFO  [LogNotificationListener] Adding notification listener for logging mbean "jboss.system:service=Logging,type=Log4jService" to server org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl@100200c[ defaultDomain='jboss' ]
12:35:42,421 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@26891082{vfszip:/C:/opt/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/company/deploy/companyVida-ear.ear/jboss-seam.jar/}
```

The "Adding notification listener for logging mbean" instruction is taking almost 3 minutes to execute.

After activating the debug level of logging, I realized that this could be the problem:

```
2018-05-03 12:34:41,280 DEBUG [org.jboss.deployment.EarLibExcludeDeployer] (main) Excluding ear's lib directory: FileHandler@18860790[path=lib context=file:/C:/opt/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/company/tmp/a2x6q4-78ufr1-jgqovqza-1-jgqovxbw-u/companyVida-ear.ear/ real=file:/C:/opt/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/company/tmp/a2x6q4-78ufr1-jgqovqza-1-jgqovxbw-u/companyVida-ear.ear/lib/]
2018-05-03 12:35:42,239 DEBUG [org.jboss.metadata.process.chain.ejb.jboss.JBossMetaDataProcessorChain] (main) Added Processor org.jboss.metadata.process.processor.ejb.jboss.SetExplicitLocalJndiNameProcessor@12f4fc5 to Chain org.jboss.metadata.process.chain.ejb.jboss.JBossMetaDataProcessorChain@11e4683
```

It's trying to delete a folder for 1 minute, and it fails. I've checked, and it's not deleted.

Can anybody help me with this issue, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make a backup of things prior to trying this, but you should be able to delete the "data", "work" and "tmp" folders.  Them start Jboss and see if it speeds things up.  If it does, I think i can give you an answer as to whats causing it

Comment: Hi JGlass I was able to delete the data, work and tmp folders inside my JBoss server folder. I did it, and the problem persisted. It's still trying to delete context=file:/C:/opt/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/company/tmp/a2x6q4-neq8rn-jgqx3ych-1-jgqx46wg-u/companyVida-ear.ear/ real=file:/C:/opt/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/company/tmp/a2x6q4-neq8rn-jgqx3ych-1-jgqx46wg-u/companyVida-ear.ear/lib/]
and it takes 1 minute :(

Comment: When you deploy your EAR(s), are you deploying them exploded or not exploded, e.g. on the server after deployment does windows show the EAR's as zip files or unzipped folders?

Comment: After the deployment, when I check the path \jboss-as\server\company\tmp, I see everything as folders. There are no zip files.

Comment: Deployments generally go to `\jboss-as\server\company\deploy` check there and you're looking for how *your* EAR, WAR or JARS are being deployed, not the ones that come with JBoss by default

Comment: Ok! It's deployed as folders. I couldn't find any zip files there.

Comment: I had the same problem too, JBoss basically keeps making copies of the deployment. Do you use web interface (JBoss Console) for deploying or do you manually drop the deployment in the deploy directory? I ask, as I can provide an answer as to how to not deploy " exploded" - likely be on Monday though!

Comment: I use JBoss at Eclipse. I set up the "server" view referencing my JBoss installation folder, and I do everything via Eclipse.

Comment: This [how to deploy a ear app as zipped from eclipse into wildfly using jboss tools pl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379151/how-to-deploy-a-ear-app-as-zipped-from-eclipse-into-wildfly-using-jboss-tools-pl) describes what you need to do.  Unfortunately I'm using the Red Hat JBoss Development version of Eclipse and can't verify that option exists (as it doesnt).  But thats basically what you need to do is deploy as a zipped archive instead exploded.

Comment: Thanks for your help, JGlass. I solved the problem, by checking the option "Listen on all interfaces to allow remote web connections" at the "Overview" tab (after double clicking my JBoss server configuration). Now it's taking ~3min to deploy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[After checking this option, my problem was solved. Now it takes only 3 min to deploy.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brqiw.png)

Comment: Glad you got it working, btw - you can select your own answer as "the answer", e.f. theres a grayed out check box under the down arrow, click it to accept your own answer